# how can I use the value from useState and set as initialState value under reducer in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am pretty new on react-redux and working on one application to migrate data into react-redux. Usually I have no problem to set up initalState with some const number however, under my following exmaple, one error comes up is `throw Error( "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.` how can I set up the initialState value that is passed from `useState`

```
const userGlobaleCount = (
): number | undefined => {
  const [value] = useState(60);
  return value;
};


export const defaultCount = {
  start: 0,
  num: 1000,
};

export const initialState = {
    num: defaultCount.num
};
```

I have tried

```
export const initialState = {
    num: userGlobaleCount() || defaultCount.num
};
```

obviously, it does not work

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  Your `useState` has no initial value so `value` would just be `undefined`.  Your redux store gets created before the components are mounted. 
 What are you trying to do?  Isn't the initial state just `defaultCount`?

Comment: I updated the post. source code of my application is way more complicated. but the idea is I want to use `userGlobaleCount` return value in initialState

Comment: I still don't get it. Where *else* do you want to use use this state? You can easily sync your components with the redux state by selecting values from redux with `useSelector`. `useState` can only be used in function components or in other hooks, not in plain function like this. Even if you were to put the `useState` in the highest level of your app so that you could call `createStore` inside the same component (which I don't recommend), the initial state of your redux store is just the *initial* state.  So it is still `60` and only ever `60`. It will not respond to changes in that state.

Comment: @jacobcan118 as the error explains, you can't use `useState` outside of a component. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Where does the value you want to set as `initialState` come from?

Comment: the value I want to set up is from the `userGlobaleCount ` `useState` hook